# Permutations & Combination question. Can't understand the flaw

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Find the number of ways of forming a group of 3 members out of 4 boys and 4 girls such that there is at least one boy in the group.

Ans-52

My approach- first select a boy using 4C1 and then select any 2 people out of the remaining 7 people using 7C2 which gives 4C1 * 7C2 = 84. Can anyone point out the flaw in my method.

Also the following method is given in suggested solution which seems logically valid too -
Answer =
total ways of selecting 3 people out of 8 - the case when all three girls are selected
= 8C3-4C3 = 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating selections and consequently getting a bigger answer.

Let be boys be $b_1,b_2, b_3, b_4$ and the girls be $g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4$.

Once you choose a boy, say $b_1$, the other two are chosen in $21$, including the choice $b_2, g_1$. So, you have chosen $b_1,b_2,g_1$.

But once you choose $b_2$ and the remaining seven again in $21$ ways, these $21$ ways include a possibility $b_1,g_1$. So, you have chosen $b_1,b_2,g_1$ again.

This exposes the flaw.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have elaborated upon it now. Kindly see.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give names to people so you can see where the problem is. Let's name the boys B, C, D, and F, and the girls A, E, I, and O.

With your method, you can choose the group {B, C, D} in three different ways:

1. Set B as the mandatory boy and then pick C and D.
2. Set C as the mandatory boy and then pick B and D.
3. Set D as the mandatory boy and then pick B and C.